# Email newsletter gradient color not rendering correctly

Tags: css, html, linear-gradients

i am new in HTML and CSS so and i am use the gradient color in my newsletter but gradient color not rendering on Emails so can anybody help me for resolve that problem
this is my style tag

```
.DivFirst
{
   padding:10px 40px;
   border-radius: 50px;
   width:500px;
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#0A284B, #135887);
   background: -o-linear-gradient(#0A284B, #135887);
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0A284B, #135887);
   background: linear-gradient(#0A284B, #135887);
   -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#0A284B',   endColorstr='#135887', GradientType=1)";
   zoom 1;
   -pie-background: linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, #C5CBC3);
   behavior: url(/PIE.htc);
}
```

this is my Html Code

```
<div class="DivFirst">
This is the best of the world
</div>
```

Comment: This question is very vague.  Where isn't it rendering correctly?  Outlook, Hotmail, Gmail, other?  Generally e-mails are best kept very simple and a bit more reserved on the styling since there are so many variations of rendering and CSS support.  I would suggest looking through these results:  https://www.google.com/search?q=email+boilerplate&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

Comment: CSS code in Emails is very limited. have a look at this site http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Answer (score 3):

I'm fairly sure that background gradients aren't support in HTML emails for most browsers. I'd recommend looking at the following links:

http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/03/13/techniques-overcome-poor-css-support-email/

http://caniuse.com/

Answer (score 0):

Emails are styled with Tables mainly.

Sadly email clients are not as "handy" as Browers when it comes to rendering CSS and HTML.

Look at the links that MikeTedeschi posted.  I also posted them but i removed them, because i missed his post.  Thumbs up for MikeTedeschi post ;)